# What's is the wrong in the program

Tags: python, if-statement

```
import random
random_Number = random.randrange(1, 4)

support = input('Write help to support ')

if support == "help":
    print("this is Rock, Paper, Scissors game ")
    play_Game = input('-enter 1 to Rock\n-enter 2 Paper\n-enter 3 to Scissors \n')
    if random_Number == 1 and play_Game == 1 :
        print('The game is draw\n Try Again!')

    elif random_Number == 2 and play_Game == 1:
        print('You lose!\n Hard luck')

    elif random_Number == 3 and play_Game == 1:
        print('You won!\n Good luck')

    elif random_Number == 1 and play_Game == 2:
        print('You won!\n Good luck')

    elif random_Number == 2 and play_Game == 2:
        print('The game is draw\n Try Again!')

    elif random_Number == 2 and play_Game == 2:
        print('The game is draw\n Try Again!')

    elif random_Number == 3 and play_Game == 2:
        print('You lose!\n Hard luck')

    elif random_Number == 1 and play_Game == 3:
        print('You lose!\n Hard luck')

    elif random_Number == 2 and play_Game == 3:
        print('You won!\n Good luck')

    elif  random_Number == 3 and play_Game == 3:
        print('The game is draw\n Try Again!')
    else:
        print('please, enter a correct number ')


else:
   print("write the true keyword")
```

**Comment: When I type 1, 2, or 3 it tells me to enter the correct number I think the wrong is in if statements. I have learned python and this is my first project. please, tell me is it a clean code?**

Comment: `input()` returns a string value, but the code is looking for integer values.  `'1'` is not the same as `1`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are comparing a **string** with an **integer**. In python `input()` returns a string. Of course, a string is never equal to an integer.

Therefore. convert the input to an integer using `int()`

```
play_Game=int(input('-enter 1 to Rock\n-enter 2 Paper\n-enter 3 to Scissors \n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be safer to keep the string type and replace the numbers with strings in the tests. This way, should something else than a number be entered in the prompt, the program won't crash.

```
play_Game = input('-enter 1 to Rock\n-enter 2 Paper\n-enter 3 to Scissors \n')
if random_Number == "1" and play_Game == "1" :
    print('The game is draw\n Try Again!')
```

Otherwise, any non numeric input would trigger an error during the conversion to int.